# How to rank only a subset of data in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have an Oracle table like below.

| ROW_NUM | CATALOG | CODE | EVENT_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | G | 30-AUG-21 |
| 2 | 2 | M | 30-AUG-21 |
| 3 | 1 | G_M | 30-AUG-21 |
| 4 | 3 | U | 30-AUG-21 |
| 5 | 1 | U | 30-AUG-21 |
| 6 | 1 | G | 30-AUG-21 |
| 7 | 2 | G_M | 30-AUG-21 |

I want to introduce a rank just for Catalog = 1 and Code = G or G_M based on earliest Event_DT. All the EVENT_DT are the same. I want the resulting table to look like this:

| ROW_NUM | CATALOG | CODE | EVENT_DT | C_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | G | 30-AUG-21 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | M | 30-AUG-21 |  |
| 3 | 1 | G_M | 30-AUG-21 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | U | 30-AUG-21 |  |
| 5 | 1 | U | 30-AUG-21 |  |
| 6 | 1 | G | 30-AUG-21 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | G_M | 30-AUG-21 |  |

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT CATALOG, CODE, EVENT_DT,
CASE WHEN CODE NOT LIKE 'G%' THEN 0 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY CATALOG ORDER BY EVENT_DT ASC) END AS C_RANK
FROM TABLE
WHERE CATALOG = 1;
```

This results in the following table. Row number 6 should have a rank of 3. However, row number 5, which has catalog = 1 and code = U is also counted towards the ranking. I thought the case statement will introduce a 0 for row number 5, it looks have done that but also counted towards the ranking.

| ROW_NUM | CATALOG | CODE | EVENT_DT | C_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | G | 30-AUG-21 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | M | 30-AUG-21 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | G_M | 30-AUG-21 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | U | 30-AUG-21 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | U | 30-AUG-21 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | G | 30-AUG-21 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | G_M | 30-AUG-21 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try adding the filter expression `CODE LIKE 'G%'` to your partition clause. This will create a sub-partition of `true/false` values. Moreover, your data may not order automatically as how you've shown it in the example if all rows have the same date. I've included an additional field `ROW_NUM` to order in the example. Based on your actual dataset, you may substitute this with a suitable field.

Eg.

```sql
SELECT
    t.*,
    CASE
        WHEN (CATALOG=1) AND (CODE LIKE 'G%') THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CATALOG,CASE WHEN (CODE LIKE 'G%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ORDER BY EVENT_DT,ROW_NUM
        )
    END as C_RANK
FROM
    my_table t
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUM;
```

| row_num | CATALOG | code | event_dt | c_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | G | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | M | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z |  |
| 3 | 1 | G_M | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | U | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z |  |
| 5 | 1 | U | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z |  |
| 6 | 1 | G | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | G_M | 2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z |  |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e0f9b69d0ab0d8b2c92bc8433567dcd4)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. When I added CODE LIKE 'G%', Oracle gives me the following error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @senanabs I've edit the answer to wrap the expression into a case expression which returns 1/0 retaining the logic. I've also added a new link to working demo using oracle 11g and also tested on oracle 18c. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That worked exactly as intended! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you onöy after the G, you can use

> ```
> SELECt "ROW_NUM", "CATALOG", "CODE", "EVENT_DT"
> , CASE WHEN substr("CODE",1,1) = 'G' 
>   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY substr("CODE",1,1),"ROW_NUM") ELSE 0 END AS "c_rwn"
> FROM tab1 ORDER BY "ROW_NUM"
> ```
>
> ```
> ROW_NUM | CATALOG | CODE | EVENT_DT  | c_rwn
> ------: | ------: | :--- | :-------- | ----:
>       1 |       1 | G    | 30-AUG-21 |     1
>       2 |       2 | M    | 30-AUG-21 |     0
>       3 |       1 | G_M  | 30-AUG-21 |     2
>       4 |       3 | U    | 30-AUG-21 |     0
>       5 |       1 | U    | 30-AUG-21 |     0
>       6 |       1 | G    | 30-AUG-21 |     3
>       7 |       2 | G_M  | 30-AUG-21 |     4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2efdbf5866fc91927f8e535b379f396)*

As you only want catalog 1

> ```
> SELECt "ROW_NUM", "CATALOG", "CODE", "EVENT_DT"
> , CASE WHEN substr("CODE",1,1) = 'G' AND "CATALOG" = 1 
>   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY substr("CODE",1,1),"ROW_NUM") ELSE 0 END AS "c_rwn"
> FROM tab1 ORDER BY "ROW_NUM"
> ```
>
> ```
> ROW_NUM | CATALOG | CODE | EVENT_DT  | c_rwn
> ------: | ------: | :--- | :-------- | ----:
>       1 |       1 | G    | 30-AUG-21 |     1
>       2 |       2 | M    | 30-AUG-21 |     0
>       3 |       1 | G_M  | 30-AUG-21 |     2
>       4 |       3 | U    | 30-AUG-21 |     0
>       5 |       1 | U    | 30-AUG-21 |     0
>       6 |       1 | G    | 30-AUG-21 |     3
>       7 |       2 | G_M  | 30-AUG-21 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d844d92ac8eb7d3c38043f3438824744)*